# yum and dnf is broken after run "conda install conda"

Tags: anaconda, fedora, yum, dnf

I'm working in python3 on Fedora 27 and I was trying to install the anaconda. After I run `conda install conda` yum and dnf are broken. Now I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from dnf.cli.cli import Cli  # :api
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import output
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/output.py", line 29, in <module>
    import dnf.cli.progress
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/progress.py", line 19, in <module>
    from dnf.cli.term import _term_width
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/term.py", line 21, in <module>
    import curses
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How did you install Anaconda? You should not have to run `conda install conda`

Comment: I would bet money that you installed conda as root. I don't recommend that.

Comment: yeah, I installed conda as root (sudo dnf install conda). It is my mistake. Do you know how to fix it?